# Add image without drag TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, image, tinymce

I wonder if theres a way to add a html code to the tinymce textbox through a link outside the texbox. Say we have a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addimage"><img src="img.jpg" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
```

And when i click the link img.jpg I would like img.jpg added to the textbox appearing as an image.
So basicly adding an image to the textbox without having to drag it there.

Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can embed a javascript function and a handler in the tinymce parent page (the page your image is located at). This function would call something like the following

```
to_add = clicked_element.parentNode.innerHTML;
tinymce.get(editor_id).execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, to_add);
```

**UPDATE:** Here is an example. You might need to tweak this code a bit, casue it will only work if the image you clicked is the only child of its parent. I suggest du work with the image attributes here instead of element.parentNode.innerHTML

```
// function to enter html element to caret position in editor
function add_element_to_tinymce(elem, editor_id){
  var editor = editor_id ? tinymce.get(editor_id) : tinymce.editors[0];
  editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, elem.parentNode.innerHTML);
}

// add jQuery handler to all images on the page
jQuery('img').bind('click', function (evt){ add_element_to_tinymce(this);  });
```

**UPDATE2:** This is the implementation of my own suggestion:

```
// function to enter html element to caret position in editor
function add_element_to_tinymce(element, editor_id){
  var editor = editor_id ? tinymce.get(editor_id) : tinymce.editors[0];
  var doc = editor.getDoc();
  var new_p = editor.getDoc().createElement('p');
  var new_img = $(element).clone().get(0);
  $(new_p).append(new_img);
  editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, new_p.innerHTML);
}

// add jQuery handler to all images on the page
jQuery('img').bind('click', function (evt){ add_element_to_tinymce(this);  });
```

**UPDATE3:** inserts image element + src attribute only:

```
// function to enter html element+src only to caret position in editor
function add_element_to_tinymce(element, editor_id){
  var editor = editor_id ? tinymce.get(editor_id) : tinymce.editors[0];
  var doc = editor.getDoc();
  var new_p = editor.getDoc().createElement('p');
  var new_img = editor.getDoc().createElement('img');
  $(new_img).attr('src', $(element).attr('src'));
  $(new_p).append(new_img);
  editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, new_p.innerHTML);
}

// add jQuery handler to all images on the page
jQuery('img').bind('click', function (evt){ add_element_to_tinymce(this);  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. how would this work in an html example?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I tried this out, but when i click an image it adds the entire page into the tinymce. So I feel we're getting closer but not really there. I don't really understand this child of parent thing. Could that be the reason for adding the entire page?

Comment: that's it (i mentioned it would work for images inside a parent element with that child only). see my edited post where i followed my own suggestion

Comment: Wow well done. It works perfectly now. Im so new to javascript and jquery but i think im making progress. Maybe you could give me a tip in how to insert the img but removing attributes like width and height? So basicly it just inserts the image with it's source (src). Iv'e started to study parent, child and sibling structure now as well.

Comment: see my edited post, i assign the src attribute to the created img-element only instead of cloning the whole img-element.

Comment: Is this some how possible to make within an iframe? I mean if below the tinymce textbox there's an iframe with images wich you can click on and they are added to the textbox. Or is it impossible to work javascript from outside an iframe?

Comment: for this you would need to apply the handler to the iframes image elements as well

Comment: Hi Thariama. Can you provide your valuable inputs on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629579/tinymce-image-drag-and-drop-issue-on-internet-explorer. i am kind of stuck here and not getting what is the issue in IE for tinymce?

Comment: @M Sach: just rturned from holidays - i will take a closer look at it soon