# Add image uploaded with uploadify to tinymce textarea

Tags: jquery, tinymce, uploadify

I'm trying to build a script that would allow me to post articles. The user should be allowed to add images at the end of the article. I would like to solve this by allowing the user to write the article first and then upload some images. When the images are uploaded, they should  automatically be added at the end of the tinymce textarea. I get the filename, but don't know how to add it to the Tinymce.
I tried with jquery's append, but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a similar solution by handling the upload operation in a tinyMCEPopup window. Once the upload is complete and I have the filename, I call the following command and then close the popup.

```
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, imgSrc);
tinyMCEPopup.close();
```

imgSrc is the path of the image.

Comment: Is there any way to extend this solution to make the image add at the end?
The problem is when I edit an article and call this command. The picture gets closer to the top than text. I would like to have the picture at the end.

Comment: Checkout the answer on this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009326/add-image-without-drag-tinymce

It shows how you can get the editor and insert contents into it. Since you can get the editor, I believe you can get the html content inside it too and modify as you want. Here's a link to the tinymce command reference which shows different ways to handle the text - http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Command_identifiers.